# Laravel 8 and JWT Auth have SSL Connection error when call API's

Tags: php, laravel, api, ssl, jwt

I am new to using JWT on Laravel, and I am developing a personal management application.
I have configured the environment with Laravel 8 for the backend, React for the frontend and I manage the authentication with JTW Token.
I then set up the Laravel project following this tutorial.
[tutorial link](https://hackthestuff.com/article/laravel-8-jwt-authentication-tutorial)

So I'm testing the APIs with Insomnia before moving on to implementing and using them in the React application.
But I have the following problem, when I call (from Insomnia) the `POST` logout API: `https://localhost:8000/api/logout` I get the error message `"Error: SSL connect error"`.

I have no idea what it comes from, also because the other APIs work correctly, and the custom ones are able to correctly retrieve data from the DB.

Do you have any suggestions or advice?

-my code:
JWT Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Validator;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class JWTController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }

    /**
     * Register user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:100',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:100|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
        }

        $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
            ]);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User successfully registered',
            'user' => $user
        ], 201);
    }

    /**
     * login user
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($validator->validated())) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Logout user
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout(true);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'User successfully logged out.']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get user profile.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function profile()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }
}
```

- api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\JWTController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api', 'cors']], function($router) {
    Route::post('/register', [JWTController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/login', [JWTController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/logout', [JWTController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('/refresh', [JWTController::class, 'refresh']);
    Route::post('/profile', [JWTController::class, 'profile']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It will fix it by changing HTTPS to HTTP  API: `https://localhost:8000/api/logout` to `http://localhost:8000/api/logout`
2. localhost does not support HTTPS